# How to Format Output for Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am new to Powershell and I have been trying to format this script to format output to be neat and left aligned. I have reviewed different websites and tutorials but I'm not sure I understand how to use the different switches and commands to make this happen.

```
    Hostname | Out-File -Filepath "\\some_path...\java_used.txt" -Append 

    Test-Path C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties | Out-File -Filepath "\\some_path...\java_used.txt" -Append 

    Get-Item C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties | Out-File -Filepath "\\some_path...\java_used.txt" -Append 

    #powershell -noexit c:\Temp\JavaDateTimeUsers.ps1
    .\JavaDateTimeUsers.ps1 2>&1 | tee -filepath c:\Temp\results.txt
```

Below is an image of the output I currently have. I blanked out hostname and username. I don't want spaces, I want it to be left aligned, and I want the last line to have a line underneath to separate each entry, as this apends.

[image: sample output]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you perhaps update your question to describe 1) What output are you expecting (exact examples would be great!) and 2) What output your _current approach_ is actually producing!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just updated the information.

Comment: Please SHOW us the output you want, because the description you give to me is very unclear..

Answer (score 0):

Just format the output as HTML. There u have any option to format your log with your needs.
Example:

```
echo <center> this is aligned to mid</center>|Out-File -Filepath "\\some_path...\java_used.html" -Append
```